Is it possible to change the kernel command line when using TPM backed FDE?
I am looking for a way to specify my own kernel command line (or more precisely, to define complementary values to the existing ones) when using TPM backed FDE.
Traditionally these would be defined in the bootloader configuration, but this is not something which can be done in my understanding in this scenario, as the cmdline is predefined in the UKI provided by Canonical through Snap.
The problem with this, is that for instance if I would like to OC my GPU, I would need to mask some values out, which can be only defined through the cmdline. (Or maybe later on, my point is there are scenarios where setting the cmdline with additional values would be needed to have a given functionality!)
So my question is, is there any way to do so that I am not aware of, or basically there is not mechanism on Ubuntu at the time of this post?
On my Arch system I enrolled my own keys and the UKI is generated locally, so in that scenario, I can embed my own kernel cmdline, but as Canonical provides their own generated UKIs, there is no way as far as I understand.
Thanks for the help!
